# Convert file to UTF-8 and preserve modification timestamp

Tags: linux, utf-8, character-encoding, timestamp

Converting files (in this case ISO-8859-1) to UTF-8 is pretty easy in Linux. Have been using:

- `find . -name "*.txt" -exec iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 {} -o {}.utf8 \;`
- `vim "+set nomore" "+bufdo set fileencoding=utf8 | w" "+q" $(find . -type f)`

Problem is that the modification timestamp will naturally be altered to conversion time. Is there any clean or even dirty way to preserve the original modification time?

Edit: Seems that there are no simple flag or option for this. Modifying the metadata is altogether change, directed against the file and affects file modification stamp...although charset conversion is imo little bit on grey area. Anyway going forward with the script way as jjacobi directed below.

Comment: You can change the modification time of a file (to any time you want) with the `touch` command.

Comment: [Can “find” command preserve access-time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137985/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can someone clarify why my question is downvoted? The question is clearly stated, I spent considerable time searching similar questions in here, googled, man pages etc. @jww your link is good, but don't work here as the chattr trick works only when reading files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be:

---

Store the old modification timestamp in a variable

```
last_modif_ts=$(stat [FILENAME] --printf=%Y)
```

*Do the desired modifications on the file.*

Modify the last modification timestamp with the touch command

```
touch -m -t $last_modif_ts [FILENAME]
```

---

See the man of the touch command if you want to modify the last access or creation time.